# How is called this type of function Listener?

Tags: kotlin, interface, listener

I want to get some information about this type of function
I want a listener, but its not setOnClickListener, or setonTouchListener, but an equivalent, that its waiting for some other information like if something is expanded, or some information change, and that data come from another Fragment. So its neccesary the use of interfaces.

I cant get any info about that. Any documentation will help a lot

Thank you!

Comment: You’re describing callbacks. A listener is (informally) a callback that is called repeatedly.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you !